# Showing progress on DataAdapter.Update() makes it to run twice as slow. Any suggestion?

Tags: c#, sql, database, multithreading, backgroundworker

I use the DataAdapter.Update() command to get any changes from my DataSet and pushing them into a local sql database.

To show progress, I use "DataAdapter.RowUpdated += DataAdapter_RowUpdated;"

So every Updated row, the DataAdapter_RowUpdated function fires. Tho it updates the database twice as slow (takes 2:22 minutes to update 50.000 records, without it, it takes 1:04 minutes)

Is there any way to not slow anything down?

```
public MainWindow()
{
    objDataAdapter.RowUpdated += ObjDataAdapter_RowUpdated;
}

//Updating database from DataSet
private void BgWorkerWriteDB_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //This divides 100 by the number of rows to update so It adds that number every iteration.
    var chData = objDataSet.Tables[0].GetChanges();
    if (chData != null)
    {
        percentagePass = 100 / (decimal)chData.Rows.Count;
    }

    SqlCommandBuilder objCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(objDataAdapter);
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ActiveInactive", objCon);
    objDataAdapter.Update(objDataSet);
}

//Firing every updated row
private void ObjDataAdapter_RowUpdated(object sender, SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    decimal temp = progress;
    progress += (decimal)percentagePass;
    if (progress > temp)
    {
        lblProgressDB.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => lblProgress.DB.Content = ((int)progress + "%").ToString());
    }
}
```

> **Found the solution, the if statement needed to round up and check whole numbers and not decimal values.**

```
if ((int).progress > (int).temp)
```

Comment: What is in the `_RowUpdated` event handler?  How long does it take to run on each invocation?

Comment: Everytime a row is Updated in the database, _RowUpdated is rised.

It´s being rised inmediatelly, so for 50.000 records, its executes 50.000 times.

Comment: That is not what I asked.  I know how the `RowUpdated` event works, I am asking you what is actually *in* your `ObjDataAdapter_RowUpdated` event handler and how long does it take to run?  You have hidden it in your code listing with a comment.  What is in here is a possible answer to your question unless you already know how long it takes to run each invocation of it.

Comment: I just added what is happening inside the handler.

Comment: My guess would be that there's too much updating of your progress bar going on.  It's hard to say for sure because the data types and values are not evident in what you've showed us, but it's possible that the `(progress > temp)` test is always passing and so you are updating the progress bar 50,000 times.

Comment: Actually (progress > temp) is to avoid updating every time.

Comment: Yes, that is what I assumed.  What I am saying is that I suspect that it is either not working or not working well enough.  I would suggest keeping tracking of how many times your code is actually updating the progress bar with a static counter somewhere.

Comment: While answering you @RBarryYoung I found out what was wrong, I wasn´t transforming the values in my if statement to integers, so it rounds up the numbers and it only updates when entire numbers change.
((int).progress > (int).temp)